# How many Binary search trees

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

I had task from school which I do not know how to solve. Can you help me with it?
Here is correct task:

> Determine the number of  different binary search trees with just 6
>   vertices, which contains these values: 27, 1, 3452, 815, 29 and 100.

Correct result it should be **132**. Can you tell ako find out that result in steps? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values themselves are not important, we just use that they are pairwise distinct. Let compute number $f(n)$ of binary search trees (BSTs) on $n$ vertices for some values of $n$.

Obviously $f(1) = 1$ since there is the only BST on $1$ vertex.
For $n > 1$ we can take any vertex as root. If we take vertex with the smallest value as root then all other $n - 1$ vertices go to the right subtree and there are $f(n - 1)$ such BSTs. If we take vertex wtih the second smallest value as root then $1$ certain vertex goes to the left subtree in $f(1)$ possible ways and other $n - 2$ vertices go to the right subtree in $f(n - 2)$ possible ways. And so on. Assuming $f(0) = 1$ we have
$$f(n) = f(0) \cdot f(n - 1) + f(1) \cdot f(n - 2) + \cdots + f(n - 1) \cdot f(0) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}f(i)\cdot f(n - 1 - i).$$
Then
$$f(1) = 1,\\
f(2) = 1 + 1 = 2,\\
f(3) = 2 + 1 + 2 = 5,\\
f(4) = 5 + 2 + 2 + 5 = 14,\\
f(5) = 14 + 5 + 4 + 5 + 14 = 42,\\
f(6) = 42 + 14 + 10 + 10 + 14 + 42 = 132.
$$
In general $f(n) = C_n = \frac{(2n)!}{(n + 1)!n!}$ where $C_n$ is the [Cathalan number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalanNumber.html).